# SQL Server - Variables Date Range

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to pull back the last seven days of data.

```
Declare @DateRange Datetime
Set     @DateRange = DateAdd(DD,-7, GetDate())


WHERE CreateDate = @DateRange
```

The above script is not working. How would I properly create this syntax and filter on the data in my where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query currently requests records whose createdate is EXACTLY 7 days ago, to the second.

What you want is to request all records SINCE 7 days ago.

```
Declare @StartDate Datetime
Set     @StartDate = DateAdd(DD,-7, GetDate())

SELECT ...
WHERE CreateDate > @StartDate
```